# Emailing a group that haven't signed a survey

Tags: 2010, workflow, survey

I'm trying to setup a reminder email that will go out to people that haven't signed a survey after a given time.

I'm trying to use workflows to do this but my SharePoint skills are lacking at this point. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you check if the survey wasn't signed? If it is a value in one of the columns, you can write a simple IF condition in the SharePoint Designer:
Workflows>List Workflow

[image]

I guess that you may also want wait after creating the item and  before reminding the users to sign a survey. Pause and wait may be a solution for you here (depending on the requirements):
[image]

You may also use Information Management Policy to start the workflow:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/431b0a5d-7b64-4653-b71f-ebd9087c348a/information-management-policy-not-starting-workflow

Try these, explore the possibilities and once you encounter an error post a detailed question describing what you are using and and why it doesn't work like you expected.